# How to find bridges in a graph using dfs?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I'm trying to check presence of bridge in a given graph but it is always returning false.
Please make me understand, why is this happening?

Here is my code:-

```
def dfs(graph, node, visited,intime,lowtime, par):
    global timer
    visited[node] = True
    intime[node] = timer
    lowtime[node] = timer
    timer += 1

    for child in graph[node]:
        if not visited[child]:
            dfs(graph, child, visited,intime,lowtime, node)
            if intime[node]< lowtime[child]:
                print('bridge found between nodes', node,'-', child)
                return True

            lowtime[node] = min(lowtime[node], lowtime[child])
        else:
            if child != par:
                lowtime[node] = min(lowtime[node], intime[child])
        # return True
    return False
```

Here is Driver Code for this function:-

```
#Driver code

inp = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,4],[3,4],[3,5],[5,6],[5,7],[6,7]] 
n = 7 #node
graph = {}
visited = {}

intime = {}  #time of contact with node
lowtime = {}
timer = 1

for i in range(1, n+1):
    graph[i] = []
    visited[i] = False
    intime[i] = None
    lowtime[i] = None
for u,v in inp:
    graph[u].append(v)
    graph[v].append(u)

print(dfs(graph,1,visited,intime, lowtime, -1))
```

Output:

```
bridge found between nodes 3 - 5
False
```

I think, I have implemented function correctly (because it is printing correctly i.e. `bridge found between nodes 3 - 5`), but don't have idea that how recursion is working inside.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the false is printed is because you always return False at the end of your dfs for loop. You have successfully found your bridges, because the second last for loop iteration returns True!! ;) If you add `print(child,visited[child],visited)` as the first line inside your dfs for loop, you can see much more details of what is going on: [image: printed output]